# Angular member sequence

Tags: angular, rxjs

The Angular [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#member-sequence) states that public properties should come before private properties. But. If I have a private Subject that I want to publically expose, how do I do that without breaking this style guide?

```
private readonly _subject$ = new Subject();

subject$ = this._subject$.asObservable();
```

The public property refrences the private one, meaning that it has to come first. If I'm to use a getter, the observable would be returned as value, not reference. Is there a trick out there I'm not aware of?

Comment: Usually I group the subject and the observable on consecutive lines regardless of the Angular style guide.